# File upload on AWS S3 Storage IOS in sequential order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I am working on chat application where I need to send media files (Image Audio Video, etc) to S3 storage using AWS IOS SDK v2.2.x.

I an sending all files for upload in a loop using `AWSS3FileTransferManager` by creating multiple upload requests. The uploads are working with callbacks coming from files in order of the one that finished first.

I am looking for an input as to how S3 can send me the finish callbacks in the same order as my upload request order.

Example:

*Order I send*

1. Image  (10KB)
2. Video (2MB)
3. Image (10MB)
4. Video (50MB)
5. Audio (5MB)
6. Image (5KB)

*Expected order received*

1. Image  (10KB)
2. Video (2MB)
3. Image (10MB)
4. Video (50MB)
5. Audio (5MB)
6. Image (5KB)

*Observed order received*

6. Image (5KB)
7. Image  (10KB)
8. Video (2MB)
9. Audio (5MB)
10. Image (10MB)
11. Video (50MB)

Can there be some provision that even if the task hass finished its work for upload, the callback is received only after its previous task are completed and sent or else queued? And if the previous task has timed-out and failed then only the immediate next task is processed?

Comment: Do you mean `AWSS3TransferManager` instead of `AWSS3FileTransferManager`?

Comment: @VickyDhas, you *do* see the pattern in the observed order, right?

Comment: @Adrian : Yes its AWSS3TransferManager , not FileTXManager , referred as given example of ADS IOS SDK Sample Codes

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : What I expect is irrelevant of the sizes they are send but always they start one after the other and not give me callback whichever are completed first. I want to perform one upload at a time even when S3 are send multiple task.

Comment: Without managing the calls and callbacks yourself, you can't control the order they're returned and hence when the callback is run.